# Query about the grass analogy in the Tehillim

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, tehillim

Shalom.

Tehillim 92 and 103 both deploy grass as an analogy, in the former to describe the wicked, and in the latter to describe Man / Adam in general.

Should we take these verses, combined, as a statement that all wickedness stems from what is common to us all - namely, the body and it’s inclinations - and that the wicked are simply the more ‘fleshly’?

Many thanks for your time.

Comment: IDK about all. A lot, definitely.